# Resolution of the generated pdf file

Tags: c#, html, pdf-generation, syncfusion

I have a problem with the resolution in a PDF file generated on the basis of HTML

I am using `HtmlToPdfConverter` from `Syncfusion` together with `WebKitConverter`

The A4 paper size is set to `595px x 842px`

I worked on `Windows 7` with an older screen. Everything was fine

When run on a `Windows 10` system with a different screen, **the paper content is larger than paper. The text is too big, the pictures are too big**

The size of the text is also set in pixels.

For sure the difference is in PPI

A code snippet with generator settings:

```
PdfMargins margins = new PdfMargins();
margins.Left = 50;
margins.Right = 50;
margins.Top = 0;
margins.Bottom = 0;
settings.Margin = margins;
settings.Orientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
settings.WebKitViewPort = new System.Drawing.Size(595, 0);
settings.PdfPageSize = new SizeF(595, 842);
```

Is it possible to set in some way that it will always work?

Answer (score 1):

The content size of PDF document may different based on machine/application where the conversion take place. If you need a same output in all the machine/application then please set a fixed viewport size in WebKitViewPort property. WebKit HTML converter internally using system viewport size for converting HTML to PDF. The system viewport size may differs based on the system and application.

Even the fixed WebKitViewPort size does not helps, please provide us the complete code snippet for the conversion, so that it will helpful for us to analyze and assist you further on this.

Please refer below links for more details about WebKit viewport.

**UG:** https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit#viewport

**KB:** https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7412/

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size in em instead of px for you text sizing. You can set the pictures in percentage. You want to make everything scaled to the paper size.

> “Ems” (em): The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document
>   media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the
>   font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems are
>   scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt, etc

**Meet the Units**

1. **“Ems” (em):** The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document
   media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the
   font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems are
   scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt,
   etc. Ems are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to
   scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.
2. **Pixels (px):** Pixels are fixed-size units that are used in screen
   media (i.e. to be read on the computer screen). One pixel is equal
   to one dot on the computer screen (the smallest division of your
   screen’s resolution). Many web designers use pixel units in web
   documents in order to produce a pixel-perfect representation of
   their site as it is rendered in the browser. One problem with the
   pixel unit is that it does not scale upward for visually-impaired
   readers or downward to fit mobile devices.
3. **Points (pt):** Points are traditionally used in print media (anything
   that is to be printed on paper, etc.). One point is equal to 1/72 of
   an inch. Points are much like pixels, in that they are fixed-size
   units and cannot scale in size.
4. **Percent (%):** The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a
   few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current
   font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the
   percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices
   and for accessibility.

**So, What’s the Difference?**
It’s easy to understand the difference between font-size units when you see them in action. Generally, **1em = 12pt = 16px = 100%**. When using these font-sizes, let’s see what happens when you increase the base font size (using the body CSS selector) from 100% to 120%

[image]

As you can see, both the em and percent units get larger as the base font-size increases, but pixels and points do not. It can be easy to set an absolute size for your text, but it’s much easier on your visitors to use scalable text that can display on any device or any machine. For this reason, the em and percent units are preferred for web document text.

https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent